# How do I get the Piranha Plant DLC?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

The Piranha Plant DLC will be released sometime February, but early buyers can receive it for free if they claim their Nintendo gold points. I bought the physical version and registered it to my account and got my gold points.

Am I supposed to get an email with the download code already? I know the DLC isn't out yet, I just want to make sure I'm eligible to receive the DLC once it's out.

Comment: I seem to remember seeing on my account somewhere that I had it, I can look for that later to see if I can find it

Comment: @Unionhawk I think you're supposed to get the email already, but I didn't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [official Super Smash Bros. site](http://smashbros.nintendo.com/buy/#piranha-plant):

> A download code* for the Piranha Plant DLC will be sent to the email associated with your Nintendo Account within 10 days after registering.
>
> *Download code expires 11:59 p.m. PT on 6/30/2019.

Considering the game only released 2 days ago, you still need to be patient for at most 8 more days.

Comment: This is true. It took just over 24 hours for me.

Comment: @Faxter Mine took longer, but I got it as well now.